# But other things being equal, it is better for society that the girl is educated than that she remain/remains ignorant

Tags: verb-agreement, subjunctive-mood, quotations, books

I found the following sentence in Neil Stephenson's Diamond Age

> But other things being equal, it is better for society that the girl is educated than that she ***remain*** ignorant.

([p. 164 in Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=aAV6wV4Rn00C&pg=PA164&lpg=PA164&dq=%22But%20other%20things%20being%20equal,%20it%20is%20better%20for%20society%20that%20the%20girl%20is%20educated%20than%20that%20she%20remain%20ignorant.%22))

I do not understand why there is remain and not remains. The problem is that I'd expect all verbs in third person singular end with `s`.

Comment: Ironically, the problem is not with *remain* but rather with *is*: the sentence ought to read *it is better for society that the girl be educated than that she remain ignorant.* This is called the present subjunctive, also known as the mandative subjunctive. There are other names for it as well; in any case, a quick look at the Wikipedia page should help you out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive

Comment: [In the Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar (1994), Chalker and Weiner note that the **mandative subjunctive** "has made a **considerable comeback** in British English in recent years, probably under American influence."](http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/Mandative-Subjunctive.htm) I'd have thought this is fairly basic grammar, more appropriate on 
[English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Paired indicatives (“it is better for society that the girl *is* educated than that she *remains* ignorant”) or—more excruciatingly correct or stuffy—paired subjunctives (“it is better for society that the girl *be* educated than that she *remain* ignorant”) would both work fine. It is only the writer’s mix-and-match approach that seems a bit off, as wishy-washy, or as if driven by some kind of usage-related status anxiety.

Answer (score 1):

It is a rare use of the subjunctive mode.  The subjunctive is used for contrary-to-fact or hypothetical situations, and when used in the present, is marked by a non-conjugated verb (variously called **base form** or **bare infinitive**.)

Past subjunctives are marked by the usual past tense forms, except **to be**, which is were for all subjects, and never **was**.)

For a complete explanation of in what cases this is used, see [this web page.](http://www.englishpage.com/minitutorials/subjunctive.html)

However, because there are two subjunctive verbs in this sentence, it should actually be

> But other things being equal, it is better for society that the girl **be** educated than that she remain ignorant.

Answer (score 0):

*Remain* is in the present subjunctive, a verbal mood that's fallen somewhat out of common usage in modern English, though not entirely. It indicates possibility or recommendation, so you can translate it as "that she may/should remain ignorant", and is used here because he's posing a hypothetical situation rather than simply saying that there's a girl who certainly is ignorant (in which case you'd always use the indicative, which, as you say, ends in -s in the 3rd-person singular). In English, the present subjunctive can always be formed by taking the infinitive form of the verb (e.g. "to be", "to go", "to say", "to die" etc.) and taking off the "to".

As noted above, one would expect to see the subjunctive form in both verbs (i.e. "that she *be* educated than that she *remain* ignorant"), though perhaps this may sound too stilted to modern ears because the irregular subjunctive form of the verb to be looks too different from its indicative forms.

"Long live the king" is another example of the subjunctive, used in that case to express a wish for the future.

Answer (score 0):

In formal contexts, particularly in written English, we can leave out ***should*** and use only the base form of the verb. The form is the present subjunctive.

> they directed that the building (should) be pulled down.

***HOWEVER***

> In less formal contexts we CAN use ordinary forms of the verb instead of the subjunctive:
>
> I suggest that he give up golf (more formal) (negative ...that he ***not*** give up golf)
>
> I suggest that he gives up golf (less formal)(negative ...that he ***doesn't*** give up )